# Netlogo coding help - split turtles into factions, follow above faction, avoid below

Tags: netlogo

I'm new to netlogo and have been combining the codes from a faction model and follow/avoid model.

I've split my turtles into factions ( displayed as different colours) and I'm trying to get them to follow the faction above them, and avoid the faction below them. If someone could have a look at my code that would be great, I think it's not working because I tried to use 'breeds'  to separate who turtles judge above/below them, and it needs to be different for all turtles. I've put the areas I think are not allowing it to work in bold..

```
breed [ above ]
breed [ below ]

turtles-own
[ faction ]

to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [ set pcolor white ]
  set-patch-size 10
  resize-world min-pxcor max-pxcor min-pycor max-pycor 
  ask patch 0 0
   [ ask patches in-radius ( max-pxcor * .9) with [  random-float 100 < density ]
     [ sprout 1
       [ 
         set shape "circle"
         set faction random factions
         set color faction-color
         set size 1.1
         judge
       ]  ]   ]
   reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [ avoid ]   
  ask turtles
  [ fd 0.1
    if any? above in-radius 360; vision in patches and degrees
    [ set heading (towards min-one-of above [distance myself]) ] ]; adjusts heading to point towards   

 ask turtles
  [ fd 0.1
    if any? below in-radius 360; vision in patches and degrees
    [ set heading (towards min-one-of below [distance myself]) + 180 ] ] ; adjusts heading to point away from wanderer

  tick
end

to judge

  if turtle color = faction-color + 30 
  [ set breed above ]

  if turtle color = faction-color 
  [ set breed same ]

  if turtle color = faction-color - 30 
  [ set breed below ]

end

;; EXTRAS

to avoid
      ifelse not any? other turtles-on patch-ahead 1
      [ fd 0.1 ]
      [ rt random 360 ]
end

to-report faction-color
   report red + faction * 30
end
```

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.
Thanks again.

Comment: I've reformatted your code to look like code, but lost the bold parts in the process. Anyway, it's usually better to mark a part of code that you want to draw attention to with a comment instead of using formatting like bold, italics, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You're not that far off. You have correctly identified that your usage of breeds is inappropriate. The attribute of being "above" or "below" is relative to the turtle that's asking, and not a property of a turtle in itself. There might be a better approach to doing this, but with minimal changes to your code, you could go with something like:

```
to go
  ask turtles [ avoid ]    
  ask turtles [
    fd 0.1
    let above turtles with [ color = [faction-color] of myself + 30 ]
    if any? above in-radius 360; vision in patches and degrees
      [ set heading (towards min-one-of above [distance myself]) ] ; adjusts heading to point towards   
  ]
  ask turtles [
    fd 0.1
    let below turtles with [ color = [faction-color] of myself - 30 ]
    if any? below in-radius 360; vision in patches and degrees
      [ set heading (towards min-one-of below [distance myself]) + 180 ] ; adjusts heading to point away from wanderer
  ]
  tick
end
```

(You can then get completely rid of breeds and of your `judge` procedure.)